# at angular 6 i try to use id property but it's not working with strong tag and innerhtml at binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular6

i am trying to build dynamic innerhtml but at bind the data it should be like

```
<strong class="strong" id="1">Admin Admin</strong>
```

but id didn't showed and it appear

```
<strong class="strong">Admin Admin</strong>
```

i use innerHtml to bind data

```
<div (click)="onClickLink($event)" innerHtml="note.description"> </div>
```